# Creating a dynamic font style across a label

Tags: c#, text, fonts

I have a label that uses special characters, and I want only the special characters to be `oblique`, and the rest of the label to be regular.

`Oblique` is a `font style` that I've been changing in the label properties.

I thought of using something like the `\n`key that adds a line to a `MessageBox` but didn't found anything like it.

Hints? Because on the properties this is not achievable either.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be impossible to do it on a regular label. As far as I know, you can set the font style only to the hole text of the label.

However, you can create your own label, override it's OnPaint method, and do whatever you want there. you will need to calculate the locations of the characters in your text, but it is possible to do.

Comment: Wouldn't concatenation of strings do it?

Comment: No, because you will need to draw regular characters and special characters with different calls to DrawString. let's say you want all 'a' chars to be italic in this string: "abcdaabcdabaaabcd". you will need to draw the first a, then the bcd, then the second and third a ect.

Comment: damn, this can't be. There are a lot of sentences who use `italic` half way, for characterizing variables, etc. How come c# has such a limitation?